# Facebook Update Status thumb issue

Tags: facebook

The Facebook "Update Status" is not getting right image of the page. When I paste the http://www.cjp.org/page.aspx?id=245692 link on my "Update Status" it only shows on thumbnail of "Charity Navigator" and completely ignores the main image. On other urls like http://www.cjp.org/page.aspx?id=235964, it shows the main image and gives options of other thumbnails.

Both pages as basically done the same way with cms, the only difference I see is the image ratio. Is that the reason why it's not getting the main image. Is there a way to show the main image without chaining the aspect ratio?

Thanks,
Rex

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook share url thumbnail problem](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4967979/facebook-share-url-thumbnail-problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have any open graph data so facebook is just guessing what images, description, title etc you want to show. You need to add open graph meta data to your head, and check it with the url linter to make sure it is reading the things you want it to show, correctly.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: Thanks Abby, but our CMS is very closed and can't put/access anything else beside the html.

Comment: Then you won't be able to control what facebook shows in the publish story. I suppose you can use the linter to debug and see how it is choosing the images to use, and try to influence that? I would really recommend taking the time to solve the problem correctly though and get the open graph data in, if you can.

Comment: I uploaded a new image(3:4) and it's showing now. I believe that it's the aspect ratio of the original image as the ratio is close to an online banner or header. Thanks for your input, I will try the OpenGraph on my personal projects.

Answer (score 0):

Use a tag like this:

```
<link rel="image_src" 
  type="image/jpeg" 
  href="http://www.example.com/image.jpg" />
```

Note, this doesn't work for everyone. It did work, but many are saying it doesn't anymore. Trying doesn't hurt.